# How can I do addition with time variable in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I was thinking this should be simple.

```
$m_time1 = strtotime('1:00:00');
$m_time2 = strtotime('5:30:00');
$m_total = $m_time1 + $m_time2;

echo date('h:i:s', $m_total);
```

The result is `3:30:00` but should be `6:30:00`

Any clue why?

Comment: This's being converted to your server local time.

Comment: `strtotime()` accepts a date, it's not suitable to use with time specifically. What you need to do is to split time strings manually, convert them to seconds manually, do any arithmetics you like, then convert back to string.

Comment: Zerkms do you have any idee where I can see an example of you solution. This make sens...

Comment: To get accurate time differences, you _need_ to specify dates. Otherwise, you encounter problems when calculating the difference between 11 PM and 1 AM, for example. Is it 2 hours or 22? Also when DST begins and ends, and other situations like that. In my experience, it's better to stick to timestamps, and only use readable format for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime()` produces a unix timestamp which represents the number of seconds between the time provided and January 1st 1970. Since you didn't specify a date in your function call, it assumes the current date at the time you passed to the function.

As a result your code above, run today produces an output of

```
$m_time1 = 1376024400
$m_time2 = 1376040600
```

When you add these together it results in a "time" of `3:30 AM` in the year `2057`.

---

To avoid this happening, you need to escape subtract the timestamp for "today" from the timestamps before adding them and then add it back again after the addition.

```
$today = strtotime("TODAY");
$m_time1 = strtotime('1:00:00') - $today;
$m_time2 = strtotime('5:30:00') - $today;
$m_total = $m_time1 + $m_time2 + $today;

echo date('h:i:s', $m_total);
```

The above code echos `6:30:00`.

[PHPFiddle Example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e6e-d5f)